# Problem on sending email with firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have created a shop application with android and firebase. What I am developing now is a trigger to send an email to the customer when the invoice of the order is created on the storage bucket.

I have tested that all the code related to the trigger is correct, but I am having problems with the `sendMail` function. Concretely the Firebase Functions console is catching `Error: Unexpected socket close`.

This is my code:

```
function sendEmail(user, email, order, type){
  console.log("Sending Email...");
  if (type == "confirmacionPedido"){
    return transport.sendMail({
      from: "COMPANY <xxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
      to: email,
      subject: "Confirmación pedido " + order,
      html: `
            <h1> Estiamdo ${user}, </h1>
            <p> Hemos recibido su pedido correctamente. Le mantendremos infromado de su estado. </p>
            <p> Gracias por confiar en nosotros </p>
          `
    })
    .then(r => r)
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Could you please refer to [this](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/830) and comment on the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed the solution exposed on the link that has passed **@John Brookfields**.

For mails to be sent from smtp.gmail.com make sure you have followed these 2 steps:

1. In your google account make sure you have 2-Step Verification enabled.
2. Then go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords. Click Select app and choose Other (custom name) from the dropdown and click Generate. You will get a 16 digit code, this code should be used as password in email configuration and user remains as your email. Also, make sure {secure: true}

Here is my configuration:

```
transport: {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: '<myemail>',
        pass: '<16 digit code generated in step 2 above>',
    },
}
```